# How do I use model settings to change my component and page image once at a time? (Octobercms)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, backend, octobercms

my model Settings.php

```
class Settings extends Model
{
    public $implement = ['System.Behaviors.SettingsModel'];
    // A unique code
    public $settingsCode = 'dca_plugins_settings';
    // Reference to field configuration
    public $settingsFields = 'fields.yaml';
    /**
     * @var array Relations
     */
    public $attachOne = [ 'avatar' => ['System\Models\File'] ];
}
```

my Fields.yaml

```
fields:
  id:
    label: ID
    disabled: true

  avatar:
    label: Avatar
    type: fileupload
    mode: image
    imageHeight: 150
    imageWidth: 250
```

my Component comp.php

```
public $avatar_id = 1;

public function getAvatarImage($avatar_id)
{
    $var = \System\Models\File::select('disk_name')->where('attachment_id', $avatar_id)->first();           
    if (count($var) == 0) return "";

    return $var->path;
} 

function setMyAvatarId($id)
{
    $this->avatar_id = $id;
}
```

my html default.htm

```
{% set avatar_id= __SELF__.property("avatar_id") %}

{% if avatar_id is not empty %}
{% do __SELF__.setMyAvatarId(avatar_id) %}
{% endif %}

<img id="avatar-image" alt="Virtual agent avatar" src="{{ __SELF__.getavatarImage(avatar_id) }}">
<script>
var avatar_id = {{ avatar_id }};
</script>
```

I manage to get a random link for my component but the image is not shown
[image: I manage to get a random link but the image is not shown]

[image: backend - model settings]

backend - model settings

Does anyone know how to define page properties? How do I link my page to the model settings?

How do I make it work? Someone pls help me~~ I'm so lost :(

Answer (score 0):

Bexie:

Take a look on the following video: http://octobercms.com/blog/post/mastering-components

Hope this helps!